# Finding addresses in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, search, find

I'm brand new to ArcMap with no training at all and very little GIS knowledge coming from MapInfo 7.8 .

What is the most efficient and quickest way to search for an address?

I update our counties phone records for the 911 dispatch system on a daily basis. Sometimes 20-30 records at a time. Using the select by attributes window for each one is sooo slow, but does open up the attribute window on it's on for each selection. The "find" tool is much faster to enter the address however after each selection, you make the changes, you have to clear the selection and clear the search box in the tool. would be nice if after I entered the address, a double click would open the attributes for that address, then again a double click on the next address would open the attribute table for that one. There are no options within the "find" tool to "create new selection" like there are for other search methods. I'm sure it sounds trivial but coming from what i'm used to the current search options are far less efficient.

Are there any good Add-Ins for improved searching?

Comment: Do you know Python? This process can be done pretty efficient with a simple script.

Comment: Open a  Edit Session, use the search by attribute tool in the table, every new search will remove the previous search selection.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking? Many options reveal themselves with a right click, in the case of the find tool you can select multiple rows (using shift key) then right click and select.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using the Attributes window from the Editor toolbar rather than the Attribute Table window from the layer's context menu.

With that you simply:

1. Start Editing
2. Select a set of features
3. Click the Attributes button on the Editor toolbar to open the Attributes window
4. Click on a feature in the top half of the Attributes window to see its field values in the lower half
5. Use the lower half to update them by typing in, using pick lists, etc.

Comment: ok i'll give that a look this morning when I do my updates.